# Bootstrap 4 card horizontal Scroll issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

i am using bootstrap card to create a basic image and text underneath.Decided to use card class since its a pretty good structure and didn't want to use too much css to make div list horizontally. what i want is like an image gallery with horizontal scroll like this
[image]

the problem is that card behavior is to get smaller as i add more cards . what is the issue here? , maybe i shouldn't use card-group?. maybe have to scrap bootstrap and write my own?

```css
.card-group {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 30rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="./index.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
  crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
 <div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="horzontal-scrollgallery">
   <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card pr-3">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="./images/chicago.jpg" alt="Card image">
     <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card pr-3">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="./images/chicago.jpg" alt="Card image">
     <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card pr-3">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="./images/chicago.jpg" alt="Card image">
     <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card pr-3">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="./images/chicago.jpg" alt="Card image">
     <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For what I have read, `card-deck` and `card-group` are responsive layouts (like all in bootstrap), so if you put more cards inside, they will be adapted on width so they all are visible. In your particular case, you can try to override the card style to have a fixed width (I tried this without success) or create your own classes of style for the approach you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your cards are getting smaller is because `.card-group` is displayed as `flex` and its card items' `flex-grow` is set to 1, which means they will take up equal widths:

[image]

[image]

To get what you want, you can define a custom class along with its default `.card-group` (so that you don't override the default card-group styles), set its overflow style as well as its children `<card>`'s `flex-basis` so that they have a default width. You will need to set card-group's wrapping style to `no-wrap` as well as the default is set up `wrap`.

#### CSS

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-group.card-group-scroll {
        overflow-x: auto;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    .card-group.card-group-scroll > .card {
        flex-basis: 35%;
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/b2jw13go/1/