# How to make multiple items fit on one row in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactstrap, reactjs.net

Sorry, Newbie React developer. I have a React Component that renders featured products:

```
return (
        <CardDeck>
            {items && items.map(item =>
                <Card key={item.itemNumber} width="100px">
                    <CardHeader tag="h3">Featured</CardHeader>
                    <CardImg top width="75%" className="card-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + item.images[0]?.ImageData} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.itemNumber}</CardTitle>
                        <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.categoryName}</CardSubtitle>
                        <CardText>{item.itemDescription}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                    <CardFooter className="text-muted">{formatter.format(item.price)}</CardFooter>
                    <Button>Order</Button>
                </Card>
            )}                
        </CardDeck>
    );
```

It crams all seven items on one row.

How do I show only three three or four items with a left and right scroll button or have multiple rows with a max three or four items per row?

**UPDATE**

I figured out multiple rows. I swapped `CardDeck` for `CardColumns` and let `BootStrap` handle it. I would still like to know how to have a horizontal scroll.

**UPDATE 2**

I got horizontal scroll working by following [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109202/bootstrap-4-card-horizontal-scroll-issue) SO Answer as an example. It puts a scrollbar underneath the group. So now, how do I make it use left and right buttons and hide the scrollbar?

**UPDATE 3**

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392199/make-a-button-to-scroll-horizontally-in-div) accepted SO answer as an example, I changed my document to:

```js
    render() {
        const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
        const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

        buttonRight.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
        };

        buttonLeft.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
                <CardGroup id="container" className="card-group-scroll">
                    {items && items.map(item =>                       
                            <Card key={item.itemNumber} tag="a" onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                                <CardHeader tag="h3">Featured</CardHeader>
                                <CardImg top className="card-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + decompressToBase64(item.images[0]?.compressedImageData)} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} />
                                <CardBody className="card-body">
                                    <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.itemNumber}</CardTitle>
                                    <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.categoryName}</CardSubtitle>
                                    <CardText className="card-description">{item.itemDescription}</CardText>
                                </CardBody>
                                <CardFooter className="text-muted">{formatter.format(item.price)}</CardFooter>
                            </Card>   
                    )}                
                </CardGroup>
                <button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

... but I am getting this error:

> TypeError: buttonRight is null

... on this line `buttonRight.onclick = function () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has mutated with no comments or answers. I asked a new question and was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574812/why-is-my-reactjs-button-not-found-by-getelementbyid)