# Why is my ReactJs button not found by getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react class component where I am trying to add left and right scroll buttons to a horizontal scroll. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392199/make-a-button-to-scroll-horizontally-in-div) accepted SO answer as an example:

```js
...
render() {
    const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
    const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

    buttonRight.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
    };

    buttonLeft.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
            <CardGroup id="container" className="card-group-scroll">
                {items && items.map(item =>                       
                    <Card key={item.itemNumber} tag="a" onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                        <CardHeader tag="h3">Featured</CardHeader>
                        <CardImg top className="card-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + decompressToBase64(item.images[0]?.compressedImageData)} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} />
                        <CardBody className="card-body">
                            <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.itemNumber}</CardTitle>
                            <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.categoryName}</CardSubtitle>
                            <CardText className="card-description">{item.itemDescription}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                        <CardFooter className="text-muted">{formatter.format(item.price)}</CardFooter>
                    </Card>   
                )}                
            </CardGroup>
            <button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
        </div>
    );
}
...
```

... but I am getting this error:

> TypeError: buttonRight is null

... on this line `buttonRight.onclick = function () {`

Comment: You are copying an answer from a vanilla approach, you are using React, its an anti pattern to query the DOM, use dedicated API for that, like `createRef`. Please read Refs and DOM section in React docs.

Comment: I think you are trying to access the button before render() function is completed.  There should be function allowing you to access it after render. componentDidMount maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access DOM parts which haven't been rendered yet. they will be available after render() function finishes.  You could use componentDidMount function to access the finished DOM.

I modified the code as the following:

```
 componentDidMount() {
      const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
      const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

      buttonRight.onclick = function () {
          document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
      };

      buttonLeft.onclick = function () {
          document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
      };


     
    }
render() {     

    return (
        <div>
            <button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
            <CardGroup id="container" className="card-group-scroll">
                {items && items.map(item =>                       
                    <Card key={item.itemNumber} tag="a" onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                        <CardHeader tag="h3">Featured</CardHeader>
                        <CardImg top className="card-picture" src={"data:image/png;base64," + decompressToBase64(item.images[0]?.compressedImageData)} id={item.itemNumber + "Img"} alt={item.itemNumber} />
                        <CardBody className="card-body">
                            <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.itemNumber}</CardTitle>
                            <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.categoryName}</CardSubtitle>
                            <CardText className="card-description">{item.itemDescription}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                        <CardFooter className="text-muted">{formatter.format(item.price)}</CardFooter>
                    </Card>   
                )}                
            </CardGroup>
            <button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You should avoid doing it this way, it is not declarative at all and relies on DOM query selectors which is a big anti-pattern in React...

Comment: I've just modified his code to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The order of events is:

1. Your code searches the DOM for the element
2. The JSX runs and generates some instructions for modifying the DOM
3. Those instructions are returned from the component's function
4. React adds those elements to the DOM

At step 1 you try to find elements which don't exist until step 4.

---

Direct DOM access in React is almost always a bad idea.

You can do it using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) but you very rarely need to.

In this case you can use a ref to get the *container* and then modify scrollLeft using regular `onClick` props.

Answer (score 1):

It's timing issue: when you run the js code the button you're looking for is not added to the page. You can execute it in the `useEffect` hook or the `componentDidMount` method, but the best way is to avoid the `.onclick` notation and use the `onClick` from react:

```js
function methodToRunOnClick(param) {
    //do something with your param
}
// code executed before the render of the code indicated in return
return (<div>
   ...
   <button onClick={() => methodToRunOnClick(20)}>move 1</button>
   <button onClick={() => methodToRunOnClick(-20)}>move 2</button>

</div>);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time your `render()` function is called, there is nothing yet in the DOM as a result of the render. You're using a document query to try and select a button that hasn't even rendered yet.

Don't do that kind of imperative event handling in React. One of the biggest benefits of React is its declarative approach. You can attach an onclick handler directly to an element in the JSX like so:

```
<button id="slideLeft" type="button" onClick={() => document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;} >Slide left</button>
```

Even better, use refs to to track which DOM element represents your container like so:

```
<CardGroup id="container" className="card-group-scroll" ref={(ref) => {this.containerRef = ref;}}>

...

<button id="slideLeft" type="button" onClick={() => this.containerRef.current.scrollLeft += 20;} >Slide left</button>
```